# How to loop array of objects as separate tables in angular8

Tags: html, angular

I am using Angular8, here I have got an array of objects as individual roles, which contains a list of users in it. Now I need to show those roles in separate tables. So I need to call the same code for 7 times as there are 7 roles with headings. Instead of calling the same code for 7 times, can it be looped along with the Role name as a heading, and if there is no data for that particular role, how can that be hidden?

HTML:

```
 <div class="mb-3" *ngIf="contactsList?.length !=0">
    <h6>Personal Lines Marketing</h6> 
    <table class="table table-hover accordion-table" id="accordionContact">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" *ngFor="let field of contactListDetails" (click)="sortContactsList(field.param)">
                    {{field.displayName}}
                    <i class="{{field.icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="width125"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let contact of contactsList.plMarketing | paginate: config ;let i = index">
                    <td *ngFor="let field of contactListDetails" class="{{field.class}}" (click)="editContact(contact,contact.contactId)">
                        {{contact[field.param]}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="width125 {{paginationDisable?'link-disabled':''}}" ><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table" title="Send Mail"
                            (click)="userDisplay(contact)"  [disabled]="isReadOnly && mode ==1"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></button>
                        </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

TS:

```
contactsList = [{
        "version": null,
        "statusCode": 200,
        "message": "Success",
        "isError": false,
        "result": {
            "plMarketing": [
                {
                    "userId": 2,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "New,New",
                    "phoneNumber": "123",
                    "faxNumber": "123",
                    "email": "new@gmail.com"
                }          
            ],
            "clMarketing": [
                {
                    "userId": 2,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "New,New",
                    "phoneNumber": "123",
                    "faxNumber": "123",
                    "email": "new@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "plUnderWrite": [
                {
                    "userId": 15,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "ghghgh,hghgh",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "sahdh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "clUnderWrite": [
                {
                    "userId": 19,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "hghg,fse",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "hgh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "plCorrespond": [
                {
                    "userId": 18,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "hghg,fse",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "hgh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "clCorrespond": [
                {
                    "userId": 15,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "ghghgh,hghgh",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "sahdh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "accounting": [
                {
                    "userId": 18,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "hghg,fse",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "hgh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "management": [
                {
                    "userId": 16,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "hghg,fse",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "hgh@gmail.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
```

So here, `plMarketing`, `clmarketing`, `plunderwriting` are all different roles, and all roles contain the same param names.

Please help me to loop without adding extra 7 times the same code.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ef7htj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: You should make that block of HTML a component that has an input for the title and the array of data.

Comment: Thanks for response, i have created a demo, could you please help me out to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**component.html**

```
 <div *ngIf="contactsList?.length !=0">
    <div class="mb-3" *ngFor="let key of keys;let i = index">
        <h6 style="font-weight: 600;">{{key | titlecase}}</h6>
        <table class="table table-hover accordion-table" id="accordionContact">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" *ngFor="let field of contactListDetails" (click)="sortContactsList(field.param)">
                        {{field.displayName}}
                        <i class="{{field.icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" class="width125"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{contactsDetails[0].result[key][0]?.userName}}</td>
                    <td>{{contactsDetails[0].result[key][0]?.faxNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{contactsDetails[0].result[key][0]?.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{contactsDetails[0].result[key][0]?.phoneNumber}}</td>
                    <td class="width125 {{paginationDisable?'link-disabled':''}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table" title="Send Mail"
                            (click)="userDisplay(contactsDetails[0].result[key][0])"  [disabled]="isReadOnly && mode ==1">Email</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  contactsList:any =[]
   public contactListDetails = [
    { param: 'userName', displayName: 'User Name', icon: 'fas fa-sort ', class:"textInputUpperCase" },
    { param: 'faxNumber', displayName: 'Fax Number', icon: 'fas fa-sort ',class:"textInputUpperCase" },
    { param: 'email', displayName: 'Email',icon: 'fas fa-sort ',class:"textInputUpperCase"  },
    { param: 'phoneNumber', displayName: 'PhoneNumber' },
  ];

  keys = []; //declared array to get all keys from result key
  public contactsDetails = [{
        "version": null,
        "statusCode": 200,
        "message": "Success",
        "isError": false,
        "result": {
            "plMarketing": [
                {
                    "userId": 2,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "New,New",
                    "phoneNumber": "123",
                    "faxNumber": "123",
                    "email": "new@gmail.com"
                }          
            ],
            "clMarketing": [
                {
                    "userId": 2,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "New,New",
                    "phoneNumber": "123",
                    "faxNumber": "123",
                    "email": "new@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "plUnderWrite": [
                {
                    "userId": 15,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "ghghgh,hghgh",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "sahdh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "clUnderWrite": [
                {
                    "userId": 19,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "hghg,fse",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "hgh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "plCorrespond": [
                {
                    "userId": 18,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "hghg,fse",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "hgh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "clCorrespond": [
                {
                    "userId": 15,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "ghghgh,hghgh",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "sahdh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "accounting": [
                {
                    "userId": 18,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "hghg,fse",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "hgh@gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "management": [
                {
                    "userId": 16,
                    "agentCode": 3343,
                    "userName": "hghg,fse",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "email": "hgh@gmail.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
    ngOnInit(){
      this.contactsList = this.contactsDetails[0].result;
      this.keys = Object.keys(this.contactsDetails[0].result); // getting all keys of result object
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-print-complex-array-object

Comment: sorry hope i didnt clear the requirement, i will make my demo more clear so you will get to know my issue

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ef7htj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html i have made my demo to work like this, here i am pasting same lines of code but with changing the heading name and the ngFor loop array name, so here instead of repeating code so many times in html, can we do in any way?

Comment: basically i need output as shown in demo, but need to reduce html code, which is repeating is my concern

Comment: I have edited demo and answer too https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-print-complex-array-object

Comment: Thanks, can we making sorting and pagination work using this?

Comment: i have voted and accepted the answer, but need some more help from you.

Comment: Yes we can implement sorting and pagination manually.

Comment: sorry one more, here if i have data inside array, then that heading and table to be shown for that particular title, or else that should be hidden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217861/discussion-between-santosh-shinde-and-bhrungarajni).

Comment: also here, if there are more objects then that is not shown here

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913176/how-to-make-icon-change-only-for-particular-table-instead-of-changing-as-whole